# Using Partial View's Controller Instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, partial-views

I'm trying to use partial view's controller instead of the view where I render it. My scenario is as following;

I have users and users can post something. Thats why I've two controller and models (users and post).

In the user's page, there is a textarea to get input of content and button to post . I've written this view **.../views/posts/_new.html.erb** as partial view and I render this **partial** in the **.../views/users/index.html.erb** and to use partial view I've used this piece of code.

```
<%= render 'posts/new' %>
```

In order to create post, I've written this method;

**posts_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.create(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

**.../views/posts/_new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :post do |f| %>
          <%= f.text_area :content, :class => "form-control", "rows" => "5", "id" => "comment", "placeholder" => "Write something to share with your mates ..." %><br/>
          <%= button_tag  "Share", :class => "btn btn-primary pull-right" do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

The problem here is, when I click the button in partial view, it goes to **Users#RegistrationController** of devise controller. Why ?

[Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables), guide tells that if there is a relationship between partials and the view that renders it, rails understands what we want to do and and use partial view's controller instead. Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be more explicit with your form..,

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
```

and initialize @post in your user#index controller action as

```
@post = Post.new
```

The problem is that in your current solution the form has no explicit url and method given and thus does not know that you want to create a post with it.

Comment: It now seems to go now to correct controller but gives this error `Couldn't find User with 'id'=`  in the **PostsController#create** of following code `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])`

Comment: but still, isn't it wrong to do `@post = Post.new` kind of initialization in **user#index** ?

Comment: it's not wrong. You can also just specify url and method but using @post is ok. For :user_id you need to pass the param with the form as well...

Comment: Why is it not getting the user's id then ?

Comment: Well, you jump to another controller and by default your user_id is not passed by rails. You have the option to create sth. like current_user which makes the user_id globally accessible or you just pass the user_id params along with submitting the form.

Comment: Do you know how to pass the user_id with the form?

Comment: No, but I want to know how :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `:type => 'submit'` in `button_tag`

```
   <%= form_for :post do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_area :content, :class => "form-control", "rows" => "5", "id" => "comment", "placeholder" => "Write something to share with your mates ..." %><br/>
      <%= button_tag  "Share", :type => "submit", :class => "btn btn-primary pull-right" do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Or change `button_tag` to `f.button` like this

```
      <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-primary pull-right" do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>
      <% end %>
```